# Why the example query with "or" do not use index?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am reading mysql [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html),

Here is a example in the manual .

The example create a  `Multiple-Column Indexes` ,the index is  `(last_name,first_name)`

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id         INT NOT NULL,
    last_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX name (last_name,first_name)
);
```

the manual said that this query will use index

```
SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE last_name='Widenius' AND first_name='Michael';
```

but the query with `or` below will not use index :

```
SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE last_name='Widenius' OR first_name='Michael';
```

## Question

why the example query with `or` , namely ,why

```
SELECT * FROM test
      WHERE last_name='Widenius' OR first_name='Michael';
```

do not use index ?

Comment: Can you proof this by showing execution plan?

Comment: However, the name index is not used for lookups in the following queries:  SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name='Widenius' OR first_name='Michael';

Comment: @Jan the manual said that

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suffice it to say that databases are not good at optimizing `OR` (or `IN` or `NOT IN`) conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

At a high level, I might describe the reason as the following.  When conditions are connecting using `AND`, the first narrows the population used for the second.  This makes indexes feasible because the conditions "nest".  When using `OR`, the conditions are independent.  I should note that some databases can handle `OR` conditions better than others.

If you want your code to use indexes, you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE last_name = 'Widenius'
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE last_name <> 'Widenius' AND first_name = 'Michael';
```

For best performance, you want indexes on `test(last_name)` and `test(first_name, last_name)`.